# Accessing memorystore in Shared VPC

Tags: redis, google-cloud-platform, vpc, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-memorystore

I have created a Memorystore instance with IP `10.190.50.3` (and this is in `us-east1`).
I have a shared VPC setup with name `my-gcp` and I also authorised the same when creating the `Memorystore` instance.

In shared VPC, I have a service project dev and I have a window machine(`10.190.5.7`). Inside that when I am trying to connect to memory store from that Windows machine, I am not able to connect to Memorystore instance.

I have also enabled egress traffic to `10.190.50.3` from all instance of `my-gcp` vpc. this vpc is setup in `us-east4`.

`tracert`, `ping` also not working form window machine for IP `10.190.50.3`.

This Memorystore instance is created in host project of vpc.

Answer (score 2):

I found the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/redis-overview#networking) updated recently:

1.The connecting client must be on the same network and in the same region (different zone within same region will also ok)  as your Cloud Memorystore for Redis instance.

2.If you are using a Shared VPC network across multiple projects, you can connect to a Redis instance that is deployed on shared VPC network on the host project. Connecting to a Redis instance that is deployed on shared VPC network in a service project is not supported.

Also here is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/quickstart-gcloud#connecting-compute-engine) on how to Connect to the Redis instance from a Compute Engine VM.

Comment: Where is it mentioned that "different zone within same region is okay"? I can't see this in their official documentation.

Comment: I found from my test that different zone within the same region worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! I too can confirm that this works. The GCP Memorystire documentation needs an update!

Comment: I have informed documentation team for necessary update.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, accessing memorystore from service project is currently [not supported](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/redis-overview#networking) in Shared VPC .

Comment: so being said that If I have a memorystore instance in host project(which should be in host project for shared vpc setup as per their docs) my connecting client must be in host project? right?  and If so then why shared vpc infect is used as term their if memory instance can only be used from same region or network?

Comment: Hey @deepak, Did you found out if connecting to a Redis instance on Host project, from service project is actually possible?. All of the documentation that I read are contradictory. I have two projects that are in the same region and VPC but I couldn't manage to share the same Redis instance.

Comment: I tried at some point is past and was able to access memory store from host project in service project.

Answer (score 0):

Now we can deploy GCP's memory store in the shared network using the private connection. Refer this [link](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/creating-managing-instances#creating_a_redis_instance_on_a_shared_vpc_network_from_a_service_project) for more details.

Steps below:

1. [Verify](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/verifying-connection) or [establish](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/establishing-connection) a private services access connection for the network in the host project that you use to create your Redis instance.
2. Make sure the [Service Networking API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/servicenetworking.googleapis.com?_ga=2.146820337.73825429.1639467251-494292202.1637054737) is enabled for both the host project and the service project.
3. Follow the steps from [Creating a Redis instance on a VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/creating-managing-instances#creating_a_redis_instance_on_a_vpc_network), but make the following modifications:

   a. Complete the optional step for setting up a private services access connection.

   b. Use the **Authorized VPC Network** dropdown to select the Shared VPC network from the host project. It is listed under Shared VPC Networks.